# monotouch iphone application promoted as ipad application

Tags: iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios, ios-universal-app

I had an app developed for iphone/ipad running correctly in the ipad. A made the mistake of changing it to universal. After this change the application in the ipad does not work correctly, any event outside the 640×960 original screen of the iphone is not clickable.

My question is, is there any fix other than create two separate views for each screen?

Thank

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without source. But I suppose you have created a view or window somewhere that is 640x960 pixels (actually 320x480 units) but has clipping (`ClipsToBounds == false`) off. This means that all subviews will be rendered but might be partially outside of your fixed size parent view.
This will prevent gestures being recognized.
First thing to check: If you are using Interface Builder, checks that all views have auto resizing masks set properly. If you're creating everything in code, also check the resizing masks there.